# jquery load in same page

Tags: php, jquery, load

i need use jquery load function in same page. for example:

```
echo"

<table style='border:1px solid #666;'>
<tr>";
do {
printf("

<td><a data-val='%s' id='ip'>%s</a><br><hr></td>

",$showrequestarr['ip'],$showrequestarr['ip']);
}
while ($showrequestarr = mysql_fetch_array ($showrequest));

/****************************chat*****************************/
if (isset($_REQUEST['userip'])) {
  $showresult = mysql_query("SELECT text FROM message WHERE userip = '$userip'");
  $showarray = mysql_fetch_array ($showresult);
}
```

this is my php page and i want after clicking load function send REQUEST using load function in same page

```
$("a").click(function() {
  var ip = $(this).data('val'); 
  $("#change").load('operator.php' {"userip":ip} );  
});
```

this is jquery code i dont know how use in this moment load function .... please help :)

Comment: It's missing a ",": `$("#change").load('operator.php',{"userip":ip} );`  or is a typo in the question?

Answer (score 2):

You are missing a comma between the url and the parameters.

```
$(function(){    
   $("a").click(function() {
      var ip = $(this).data('val'); 
      $("#change").load('operator.php', {"userip":ip} );  
   });
});
```

Comment: @user1360571: What you mean by  $_REQUEST is not responding ? Are you getting any script errors ? Use firebug and see what it is